# What to infer from a given scatter plot?

Tags: bigdata, visualization

I am quite new to data science and I have been given the task to find relationship between two entities for a given data.This is the scatter plot graph I made

[image]

It is a time series data.Here x axis is the mean and y axis is the mse (mean square error).

What I can infer from this graph is the mean and mse don't really go along with each other.In other words when mean and mse doesn't share any strong relationship?Is my understanding of the graph correct?Is there anything else that can be found?

Comment: Check out [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)

Answer (score 3):

It is not easy to say based on this graph. Maybe if you could apply a transformation, it was easier to see a trend. I would have at least plotted them on log-log, log-linear, etc. to get better idea.